# Are two questions dupes if one question is the answer to the other?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I am aware that, to be marked as duplicates, two questions don't have to be *identical*, as long the correct answers to both are functionally the same. As a silly example, "What is the capital of Maryland?" and "In what city does the Maryland House of Delegates meet?" could conceivably be dupes of each other, because the answer to both is Annapolis, and they are asking after it in closely related ways.

But what if one question is "What is the capital of Maryland?" and the other is "Of what state is Annapolis the capital?" That is, one *question* is the *answer* to the other. From a literal perspective, these obviously aren't the same question, nor do they have the same answer. On the other hand, from a more pragmatic perspective, reading one will clearly give you the information you need for the other.

Is there a guideline or consensus about how this situation should be handled?

---

The specific case that prompted me to wonder this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746969/what-does-the-asterisk-mean-as-the-first-argument-in-the-signature-of-a-functi/67747041), which was closed as a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821877/function-call-with-named-unnamed-and-variable-arguments-in-python); essentially "I see this code. What does it do?" and "I want to do this thing. How do I code it?"

Comment: This doesn't really answer your more general question, but I can definitely say that this dupe closure was not accurate. Nowhere in the target it even talks about a ***bare*** asterisk which is what the original is asking about...

Comment: @Tomerikoo That is an additional wrinkle, for sure. It's true that it's.not mentioned in the question itself, but it *is* mentioned and explained in the accepted answer. But yes, I'm also curious about the broader situation, in which they're more-perfect mirrors of each other.

Comment: It's true that it is mentioned, but it is rather a "by the way" note and doesn't really focus and explain that to detail. But again, I'm focusing on the specific case and not the more interesting general case you raised, which I don't have an answer to

Comment: I would say that *What is the 26th-most populous city in Maryland (as of 2021)?* is **not** a dupe of *What is the capital of Maryland?*, but *Of what state is Annapolis the capital?* is. Because the piece of information "Annapolis is the capital of Maryland" does not resolve the question "What is the 26th-most populous city in Maryland?"

Comment: @khelwood That's an excellent point, thank you. I've edited the question to have what I think is a better (but of course, still silly) example.

Comment: I noticed this question while removing the inaccurate [asterisk] tag; even with my very limited knowledge of Python, I could tell that dupe target seemed like a poor choice.

Comment: Yes, I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments), as Tomerikoo points out in [this comment on the closed dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746969/what-does-the-asterisk-mean-as-the-first-argument-in-the-signature-of-a-functi/67747041#comment119778593_67746969), is a much better fit.